# Narrowing Conversion of unsigned int to short unsigned int

Tags: c++, c++11

> warning: narrowing conversion of '(stride * 4u)' from 'unsigned int' to 'WORD {aka short unsigned int}' inside { } is ill-formed in C++11 [-Wnarrowing]

I cannot figure out why I am getting this warning compiling the following code from MinGW:

```
unsigned stride = 3;

D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 NORMALELEMENT =
{ 0, stride * sizeof(gs_scalar), D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT3, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_NORMAL, 0 };
if (useNormals) stride += 3;
```

It is complaining about the `stride * sizeof(gs_scalar)` (gs_scalar is `float`) inside those braces, but I do not see how this is a narrowing conversion since `sizeof` returns the number of bytes. I tried changing `stride`'s data type to WORD, DWORD, CHAR, everything, but I keep getting the same or similar warning.

Comment: Using brace initialization prevents narrowing conversions in c++11. Have you tried wrapping `stride * sizeof(gs_scalar)` in an explicit cast if that's your intention?

Comment: It's an *error* in C++11, not a warning...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the definition of `D3DVERTEXELEMENT9`:

```
struct D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 {
  WORD Stream;
  WORD Offset;
  BYTE Type;
  BYTE Method;
  BYTE Usage;
  BYTE UsageIndex;
};
```

(from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx but removed the typedef things).

Thus your are initializing `NORMALELEMENT.Offset` with `stride * sizeof(gs_scalar)`.

The type of `sizeof(gs_scalar)` is `std::size_t` which is apparently `unsigned int` on your platform, and the type of `stride` is `unsigned` (i.e. `unsigned int`), so the type of `stride * sizeof(gs_scalar)` is `unsigned int`. But the type of `NORMALELEMENT.Offset` is `WORD` which is `unsigned short`.

I guess that on your platform `unsigned int` is 32-bits wide but `unsigned short` only 16-bits wide, so this is indeed a narrowing conversion (if the value of `stride * sizeof(gs_scalar)` can't fit in 16 bits you'll lose data).

Even if you define `stride` as a `WORD`, it is promoted to `unsigned int` in the multiplication with `sizeof(gs_scalar)`, so the situation keeps the same.

If you're sure that `stride * sizeof(gs_scalar)` will never be more than `USHRT_MAX` (i.e. for you 2<sup>16</sup>−1 i.e. 65535), which seems likely (in the example it's 3 * 4 i.e. 12), then you can use a cast (as said by Troy in the comments), e.g. `static_cast<WORD>(stride * sizeof(gs_scalar))`.

Answer (score 2):

`stride` is `unsigned` so its value could be too large to fit into an `unsigned short`. Furthermore `sizeof` has type `std::size_t` which is also larger than `WORD`.

If you make `stride` a `const unsigned`, then the compiler can see that the actual value `12` does fit into `unsigned short` and the error goes away. But if it is not a constant, you need to explicitly guarantee that the calculation will fit because initializers inside braces are not allowed to truncate or overflow. ("Narrowing" refers to losing data, alluding to chopping off digits on one end of a number.)

Just use `static_cast< WORD >( … )`.

Comment: That thing about `const` is interesting.

Comment: @user2734025 Please upvote if helpful and click the checkmark if it solves the problem. Thanks for the well-phrased question.